# Spring Boot Referential integrity constraint violation only on the server in the pipeline

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

When running my integrations test on the local machine, everything go as expected, but when I run these tests inside the pipeline in the IBM Cloud, I got these exceptions

> 2021-07-14 10:36:21.002 DEBUG 1027 --- [    Test worker]
> org.hibernate.SQL                        :
> delete
> from
> location
> 2021-07-14 10:36:21.003  WARN 1027 --- [    Test worker] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23503, SQLState:
> 23503
> 2021-07-14 10:36:21.003 ERROR 1027 --- [    Test worker] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Referential integrity
> constraint violation: "FKLWXQ52YFUYMI2I83EIJ0PU1SI: PUBLIC.RESOURCE
> FOREIGN KEY(LOCATION_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.LOCATION(ID) (1)"; SQL
> statement:
> delete from location [23503-200]

It looks like it does not somehow delete data from the `Location` table and then when deleting the `Resource` table, it fails on the constrain violations. Do you have any idea, why is this happening?

Pipelines are running inside the **Ubuntu container** and I am developing on the **MacOS**

This is the data manager that runs before each test case

```
@BeforeEach
fun setUp() {
    dataManager.cleanDatabase()
}


fun cleanDatabase() {
    ingredientRepository.deleteAllInBatch()
    articleRepository.deleteAllInBatch()
    locationRepository.deleteAllInBatch()
    resourceRepository.deleteAllInBatch()
}
```

and these are the entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "resource")
class Resource(

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val name: String,

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    val status: ResourceStatus,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id") // nullable = false
    val location: Location,

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "resource_operations", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "resource_id")])
    val operations: List<ResourceOperation>
) : AuditableEntity()
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
class Location(

    @Column(nullable = false)
    val name: String,
) : AuditableEntity()
```

(ID is in the auditable entity)

Answer (score 1):

You have location reference in the Resource entity(Foreign key relationship)
Location is parent and Resource in child, first your have delete resource then delete location otherwise you will get `Integrity Constraint`

Or else add `CasecadeType.ALL` in parent table, it will delete child record when deleting from parent table.

Comment: Did you add cascade all on oneToMany mapping

Comment: I do not have a reference in the Location table/entity back to the Resource. (Location ID is stored in the Resource table and there is no reference in the Location table back to the Resource). I added CascadeType.DETACH on the Resource, because ALL did not work. This also did not solve the problem.

Comment: No you have location reference in resource table and parent is location and resource is child based on your entity implementation.

Comment: So, should I add List<Resource> to the Location and then add CascadeType.ALL on it?

Comment: Yes you have to